# Does splitting up data between multiple (N) tables result in linear or exponential slowdown during querying?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

### Question

I am currently wondering about the performance implications of splitting up data between multiple tables.

Specifically, I am wondering how the number of tables accessed during a query (via multiple joins) impacts query time - and whether the slowdown usually grows in a linear fashion `O(c*n)` with the number of tables `n`, or whether the slowdown usually grows in an exponential fashion `O(c^n)`.

**TLDR: By having more joins, can I typically expect a linear growth in query time, or an exponential one?**

**Footnote: I understand that this question depends on a number of different factors (e.g. Table schema/number of rows/query type. However, I am asking for a general rule of thumb)*

### Example

Lets say we are tasked with retrieving information about people and their respective occupations from the following database. Presumably, we will need to perform a join in our select statement.

```
SCENARIO A)

Person_Table
 _______________________________
| (PK) ID | Name  | Age | Race  |
|---------|-------|-----|-------|
| 0       | Jack  | 24  | Asian |
| 1000    | Tom   | 35  | White |
| 2000    | Robin | 11  | White |
| ...     | ...   | ... | ...   |

Occupation_Table
 ______________________________
| (PK) ID | (FK) PID | Job     |
|---------|----------|---------|
| 0       | 0        | Cook    |
| 1       | 1000     | Cook    |
| 2       | 2000     | Teacher |
| ...     | ...      | ...     |
```

Now consider this slightly different database schema representing the same data. With this one, we will not have to perform a join.

```
SCENARIO B)

Person_Table
 _________________________________________
| (PK) ID | Name  | Age | Race  | Job     |
|---------|-------|-----|-------|---------|
| 0       | Jack  | 24  | Asian | Cook    |
| 1000    | Tom   | 35  | White | Cook    |
| 2000    | Robin | 11  | White | Teacher |
| ...     | ...   | ... | ...   | ...     |
```

How will performance compare between these two tables?

Will `SCENARIO B` be faster by a factor of `c*2`?
Will `SCENARIO B` be faster by a factor of `c^2`?
Will `SCENARIO B` be more or less the same as `SCENARIO A`?

How will these differences generalize to more extreme examples involving 3/4/5/etc distinct tables & joins?

**Footnote: In my examples - `(PK)` stands for primary key, `(FK)` stands for Foreign key*

Comment: You are asking about the implemention of an abstract operator on abstract values without giving an implementation. That cannot be answered without giving an introduction to the topic. That's too broad. Moreover such questions are nevertheless SO faqs. Plus this is not researched. Research relational DB query optimization/implementation. See the chapter in any textbook on relational DBMSs & documentation for specific ones. See [ask], other [help] links, hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: I understand that your question is pure theoretical. However, it is still very strange, IMHO. People use SQL not to get EVERYTHING. It is used for getting "filtered" data. So for small tables without filtering your question might have some reason, but the process would be very fast anyway and so question does not make much sense (you only need spend time on optimising critical sections in your system). For big tables you have to use filtering (WHERE) and this would be the main work, not just joining. So the question does not make sense again.

Comment: As per HOW the MySQL processing joins, you have to read about explain at least. There are different strategies for that. And they have different computation hardness. You do not know what strategy will be used only looking on query. Optimiser may change the query (and strategy) when table statistics changed.

Comment: One cannot talk about the complexity of implementing an operation going from one state to another state without giving an implementation algorithm using given implementation operations with given costs on an implementation data structure. You didn't give an implementation; there is no single standard implementation. You haven't asked a meaningful question about complexity. There is no "general answer." Do some DBMS implementation research & think about what it means to ask about complexity of an algorithm. (Look at 1 answer [sic] post: "read", "written", storage", "partitions", "index", etc.)

Comment: Some queries won't see much change; some will be slowed down a lot.  _Cannot make a general answer._

Comment: Data warehousing/OLAP involves heavy querying compared to OLTP & presentation of it discuss pre-joining & snapshotting tables vs normalization & joining on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that in your scenario you would find a significant difference. Only because the number of jobs are limited and you can use an inner join(most people have only one job).

Problems start on big  tables and left/right (outer) joins which need lots of memory and swap space and where you don't reduce the number of rows.

And when you do left and right join and union them for a full outer join, then you know why mysql hasn't implemented it.

In  short as long as your database is small, you don't have lots of connections and the server hardware is decent enough, you won't feel a thing

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, I am obviously asking about non-trivial examples. 

Your answer did not address my question.

Comment: I think it does, as you encounter performance problems that no index can eliviate, you switch to another provider with mire power or one of the cloud providers. And as i saud, you won't notice not that till your database reaches its limits. A linear progrssion is not possible, only because of the joins

Answer (score 1):

Query performance is related much more to the volume of data being processed than to the number of tables.

The volume is basically in three categories:

- Rows that need to be read from permanent storage.
- Rows that need to be written to permanent storage.
- Intermediate movement of data, to support aggregations and joins.

In your example, the `persons` and `occupations` tables appear to be "vertical partitions" of the data.  That is, a single record has columns split across different tables.

In such a scenario, a query on *all* columns will be slower in the multiple table version.  However, a query on a subquery might only need to read one of the tables and would be quicker.

In any reasonable schema, an index would link the two tables.  So, the two table approach has to read slightly more data and do an index lookup.  It will be some constant slower than the one-table version for the query you specify.